Linear independence of tensor products $\{v_i \otimes w_j\}$ without choice
Let $V$, $W$ be vector spaces. Suppose $\{v_i\} \subseteq V$ and $\{w_j\} \subseteq W$ are linearly independent. Then $\{v_i \otimes w_j\} \subseteq V \otimes W$ is linearly independent. The usual proof proceeds by extending both into bases, defining bilinear functions $B_{mn} : V \times W \to F$ with $B_{mn}(v_i, w_j) = \delta_{mi}\delta_{nj}$, and using this with the universal property to show all coefficients of a linear combination equal to zero must be zero.
The problem is in the very first step, where we extend the sets into bases. I'm doing a write-up on tensor products, and I'd like to avoid discussing the technicalities surrounding the axiom of choice. So I'm looking for a proof that doesn't use choice, if one exists.
Alternatively: without the axiom of choice, is this theorem still true?
Edit: It seems that this question is answered on MathOverflow. However, this to me seems to depend on the statement that if $V' \subseteq V$ and $W' \subseteq W$ are subspaces, then $V' \otimes W'$ is isomorphic (as a bilinear space) to the subspace of $V \otimes W$ spanned by $v \otimes w$ with $v \in V'$ and $w \in W'$.
If so, how do you prove this? If not, how do you justify that the non-existence of a linear dependence in $V' \otimes W'$ implies the same for $V \otimes W$?

See here on MO (it's the second part).

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks for the link. However, I still have questions about the argument presented there.

You're welcome! I only commented precisely in case you wanted a more detailed argument. Indeed this part of the argument doesn't seem to be completely trivial. Are you defining tensor products as a quotient? As per usual it might help to say where you're getting stuck. Note that $V'$ and $W'$ are finite-dimensional here. I haven't worked out all the details but it seems to me that one can argue by working in suitable finite-dimensional subspaces. Here is also a more high-powered approach which I definitely haven't fully comprehended at this point.

Ah, underflow is right - my previous comment is just a response to the question in your edit. I forgot to go back and check if your edit corresponded with the linked post!

@underflow So, to prove this statement, you need to use the quotient definition for the tensor product? This feels a bit odd considering how the universal property is supposed to be the "actual" characterization for the tensor product.

I get what you mean - the universal property is often a good/"nice" way to prove things about the tensor product - but I don't think it's that odd. The universal property is only a characterisation after all, not a definition. You need the quotient definition to prove the tensor product exists! And the quotient definition is really quite intimately connected to the universal property anyway. Besides, the usual proof essentially goes through the "bases" definition!

Thanks, I think I've gotten the hang of the proof now. I'll do a write-up shortly.

As OP notes in their edit, the key lemma is the following:

Lemma 1: Let $C$ be the category of $k$-vector spaces. Then $\otimes : C^2 \to C$ preserves monomorphisms.

It suffices to show the following, slightly stronger lemma:

Lemma 2: Whenever $k$ is a field, all $k$-vector spaces are flat $k$-modules.

Recall by Theorem 2.5 here that an $R$-module is flat if and only if it is the filtered colimit of finitely generated free $R$-modules; this theorem is proved purely constructively in the link provided, so no choice is necessary.
Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space. Let $J$ be the full subcategory of $C / V$ with object part $k^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. More precisely, the objects of $J$ are pairs $(k^n, \phi : k^n \to V)$ with $\phi$ linear, and the morphisms $\tau : (k^n, \phi) \to (k^m, \psi)$ are linear maps $\tau : k^n \to k^m$ such that $\psi \circ \tau = \phi$. I claim that $J$ is a filtered category. In fact, $J$ has all finite colimits, which follows from the fact that any finite colimit of finitely generated free vector spaces is itself free and finitely generated (note: this is the one part of the proof which is slightly non-constructive: it requires us to assume we're working with a discrete field, but again, no choice is necessary).
Now consider the forgetful functor $U : J \to C$, $U(k^n, \phi) = k^n$, and for all $(k^n, \phi)$ in $C$, let $i_{(k^n, \phi)} = \phi : U(k^n, \phi) \to V$. Then it is straightforward to see that $(V, i)$ is the colimit of $U : J \to C$, so $V$ can indeed be written as the filtered colimit of finitely generated free vector spaces. Therefore, $V$ is flat. This concludes Lemma 1. $\square$
With Lemma 2 in hand, we now proceed to prove Lemma 1. Suppose we have $i_1 : W_1 \to V_1, i_2 : W_2 \to V_2$. Then we have, by the flatness of $W_2, V_1$, injections $i_1 \otimes W_2 : W_1 \otimes W_2 \to V_1 \otimes W_2$ and $V_1 \otimes i_2 : V_1 \otimes W_2 \to V_1 \otimes V_2$, so $i_1 \otimes i_2 = (V_1 \otimes i_2) \circ (i_1 \otimes W_2)$ is also injective. This concludes Lemma 1. $\square$
We can now use Lemma 1 to conclude the proof. If we have independent sets $\{v_i\}_{i \in I}$ in $V$, $\{w_j\}_{j \in J}$ in $W$, then we equivalently have linear injections $v : k^{\oplus I} \to V$, $w : k^{\oplus J} \to W$, which give rise to a linear injection $v \otimes w : (k^{\oplus I} \otimes k^{\oplus J}) \to (V \otimes W)$. And $k^{\oplus I} \otimes k^{\oplus J}$ is naturally isomorphic to $k^{\oplus (I \times J)}$, which gives us a linear injection $k^{\oplus (I \times J)} \to V \otimes W$. This linear injection, through a bit of computation, corresponds to the linearly independent set $\{v_i \otimes w_j\}_{(i, j) \in I \times J}$ in $V \otimes W$.
